# Count item in xml

Tags: android

i'm getting an RSS feed like the following:

```
        <item>
        <caterory>sports</category>
        <content:encoded>text 1......</content:encoded>
        <title>title 1...</title>
        </item>

        <item>
        <caterory>news</category>
        <content:encoded>text 2......</content:encoded>
        <title>title 2 ...</title>
        </item>

        <item>
        <caterory>sports</category>
        <content:encoded>text 3......</content:encoded>
        <title>title 3 ...</title>
        </item>

         ......

        <item>
        <caterory>news</category>
        <content:encoded>text x......</content:encoded>
        <title>title x ...</title>
        </item>
```

I would like to create a list ,and the listitems should be named as the category name.So,if the user click on sports,he could see the sports new, etc.
How easy is this to be done?
Searching the net i haven't found something similar.
As now, i have created a list witch returns me a list with all the categories (ex. if i have 25 articles, i get a list with 25 categories,sometime the same,as 1.sports,2.news,3.sports,...etc)

```
int position=1;
if (feed.getItem(position).getCategory()!=null)
{


for(int pos=0;pos<feed.getItemCount();pos++){

    //feed.getItemCount();

    SlideMenuItem item2=new SlideMenuItem();
    item2.id = MYITEMCATEGORY;
    item2.icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_full);
    item2.label = feed.getItem(pos).getCategory();
    slidemenu.addMenuItem(item2);
}
```

Sorry for my bad syntax,hope my question is understandable..:)

Comment: are you want to parse those item or you already parse it but can not able to disgusted ?

Comment: i have parsed them,and i know that there are 60 categories in total.That i would like to know is that from the 60 categories,the 30 is sports and the other 30 is news

Comment: you can differentiate  those while you parse it, i dont seem requirement to filter those in different class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Set with all the categories, this will eliminate the duplicates.
Then iterate the Set and add them one by one to the menu.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Try this:

```
int position=1;
if (feed.getItem(position).getCategory()!=null)
{
    Set<String> categories = new HashSet<String>();
    for(int pos=0;pos<feed.getItemCount();pos++)
        categories.add(feed.getItem(pos).getCategory();

    for(String category : categories) {
        SlideMenuItem item2=new SlideMenuItem();
        item2.id = MYITEMCATEGORY;
        item2.icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favorite_full);
        item2.label = category;
        slidemenu.addMenuItem(item2);
    }
}
```

Comment: something more specific please?:)

Comment: thanks!!that works.but then,if i want to make an action when i click every category?for example,create a tost with every title that has this category?

Comment: Then you would have to add a listener to the views that display the list item. you can use myView.setOnClickListener() method to do that.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the slidemenu, but what is it that doesn't work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28445/discussion-between-androidde-and-tbkn)